# Woocommerce Paypal Payments v 2.0.0 Unexpected token 'T', "This email"... is not valid JSON

Tags: json, woocommerce, paypal, payment, checkout

When users utilize the advanced paypal checkout (direct credit card entry) on the website checkout.

After they click "place order" they receive this error string at the top of the page.
"Error: Unexpected token 'T', "This email"... is not valid JSON paypal checkout"

Reverting back one version to 1.9.4 or 1.9.5 fixes the issue.

No response from Woocommerce support yet.  Is this on them or something I need to modify on the site code somewhere?

Upgraded to v 2.0.0 of plugin causes the error.  Reverting back to 1.9.5 or 1.9.4 solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's on the plugin creators to ensure that the response to the PayPal JS SDK's fetch call is valid JSON that can be parsed.

In case it helps understand, here's a simple demo of a similar integration pattern (not advanced in this case just regular PayPal standard, but the concept is the same): https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

If fetches don't receive JSON back from the server but instead some other output (any other HTML or text, such as a WooCommerce error page or whatever) they will error out.